# Variadic generic type alias

Tags: python-3.x, type-hinting, mypy

I'm writing a python typing stub for use with mypy. There are a lot of functions that take callback parameters of the form `Callable[[*foo], Any]`, where `*foo` represents zero or more types. I would like to be able to use a generic type alias to reduce repetition.

Generic type aliases are documented [here](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generics.html#generic-type-aliases), but I don't see how it would be possible to have a list of types as a parameter.

I know that this can be done with a concrete number of arguments:

```
T = TypeVar('T')
Callback0 = Callable[[], Any]
Callback1 = Callable[[T], Any]

def foo(f: Callback0): ...
def bar(f: Callback1[str]): ...
```

What I'd like to declare instead is something like:

```
def foo(f: Callback[]): ...
def bar(f: Callback[str]): ...
```

If it matters, the code is for Python 3.3, and I'm running mypy with Python 3.7.

Answer (score 0):

What about [protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html?#typing.Protocol)?

```py
T = TypeVar("T")


class MyAwesomeProtocol(Protocol[T]):
    def __call__(self, a: T) -> Any:
        pass


def foo(f: MyAwesomeProtocol):
    ...


def bar(f: MyAwesomeProtocol[str]):
    ...
```